# How to use Prims algorithm in 3d space

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

I was wondering how I could use Prim's algorithm in 3d space. To put it into context: I want to calculate all possible and the shortest/most efficient way/s to lay a cable in a wall with considering some unusable spots/constraints in 3d space.

Any ideas how it could modeled (algorithmically as well as technically)? I do know common shortst path and min/max spanning tree algorithms but learned/used them just in 2d space till now.

Comment: Prim's algorithm operates on a graph, not a 2D space.

Comment: I have an intuition how to map a graph into 2D space (in Java for example). That's what I wanted to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply convert your 3D wall to a graph. Let's say our wall is a simple cube, we divide it into many small cubes:

[image: 3D grid]

For every intersection you create a new vertex in your graph and for each line between intersections you create a new edge in your graph.

Since you end up with a regular graph, you can use Prim's algorithm.

You can omit vertices and edges where the obstructions are and decrease the size of the cubes if you want a higher granularity.